# django get sum of column based on where clause

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have read the documentation related to django aggregation but I am still have trouble figuring out how exactly I can get a sum of points per user.

Here is what I tried:

```
ModelName.objects.filter(username=rUser.username).aggregate(Sum('points'))
```

I get the following error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8001/mypage/
Django Version: 1.4.8
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
global name 'Sum' is not defined
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to import [Sum](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Sum) first:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
```